# Getting back multiple null values before getting back data in fetch request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach

how do I deal with getting back null in fetch requests? Eventually the request goes through but for some reason it gives back bunch of nulls before getting the data. could this be something wrong with my code or is this just normal fetch behavior?

Fetch setup

```
const [subDomains, setSubDomains] = useState(null)
const [website, setwebsite] = useState("twitter.com")

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
    const response = await fetch("api_url="+website,{ 
        headers: {
          "X-Api-Key": "hidden"
        }
      })
      const data = await response.json()
      const subdomains = data["ContributingSubdomain"]
      const convertedsubdomains = Object.keys(subdomains)
      let otherdomains = []
      for(let i=0; i < convertedsubdomains.length; i++) {
        const subdomains2 = data.ContributingSubdomain[i]["DataUrl"]
        otherdomains.push(subdomains2)
      }
      setSubDomains(otherdomains)
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [website])
```

Then the **subDomains** prop is passed on to a component as **domains**

```
const SubDomains = ({domains}) => {

    
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {domains.forEach((e) => 
                    <h2>{e}</h2>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SubDomains
```

I get an error saying **TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'forEach')**

When I **console.log(domains)**, I see that I get a bunch of nulls before getting the actual data, which I assume is causing the above error. but I don't know what I'm doing wrong when requesting the data and passing it on[image]

Comment: You are initializing subDomains as `null`, so it's always going to be `null` for at least the first render.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know why it returns keeps returning null before getting back the response, but since you initialized `subDomains` to null it'll return null for the very first render. But to fix the

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'forEach')

all you have to do is check if `domains` has a value before mapping the values.

You can change this line:

```js
{domains.forEach((e) => 
   <h2>{e}</h2>
)}
```

to:

```js
{domains?.forEach((e) => 
   <h2>{e}</h2>
)}
```

Notice I added a question mark before domains. It's [the optional chaining operator (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). It enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

Also, why not map the values, rather than `forEach`. Like so:

```js
{domains?.map((domain, index) => 
   <h2 key={index}>{domain}</h2>
)}
```

If there are IDs that come along with the domains, then you can use those as the key instead of the index.

Comment: Thanks @Ogheneochuko Pedro.  As far as I can tell, you're the only person on the Internet providing an answer to the error message "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'forEach')".   I was using mystring.match( [regex expression here] ).forEach() and no matter whether or not matches were found, the end result was this error message (after successfully finding any matches).  The ?. operator solved this issue for me.